Parallel computing for sequentially dependent tasks
I understand that Python multi-processing and multi-threading can accelerate running independent tasks. However, If I have 10 tasks sequentially and each one's input rely on the previous one's output, is it still possible to accelerate using parallel computing or parallel processing? Any perspective from software or hardware will be appreciated!

If the tasks are as you describe, then the answer is just "no".

@DavidW if keep running sequentially, would using a workstation that has more CPUs or cores help?

No. If it's truly serial like you describe then adding more CPUs would not help.

You might find that the individual tasks can be split up into parallel subtasks (possibly automatically by whatever libraries you are using). In which case it isn't actually like you describe though.

No. You have to find some part of the sequential task that can be done in parallel with no dependencies on previous results. Simplest form of this is changing from scalar arithmetic in a for loop to vectorised SIMD forms if the compiler supports them.

If it's the kind of task that has input data that can be processed chunk by chunk through the whole sequence of tasks, then yes, you can use multiprocessing.Queue to pass chunks of data from one task to another and (for example) task 2 can be processing chunk 1 in parallel with task 1 processing chunk 2 (etc. etc.). Or if it's the kind of task where, say, task1 can be parallelised, you could use multiprocessing.Pool to do that

When tasks depend on each other sequentially (where the output of one task serves as the input for the next), parallel computing becomes less effective. This is because the dependent task can't start until its prerequisite task finishes. However, you can read about pipeline parallelism:
This involves splitting a series of tasks into stages and executing each stage in parallel across different data.
Example Scenario
Assume you're processing a list of images sequentially, and each image goes through a pipeline like this:
Task 1: Read and preprocess an image.
Task 2: Apply a filter to the image.
Task 3: Analyze the filtered image for features.
Each task depends on the output of the previous one, making them inherently sequential for each image. However, if you have multiple images, you could apply pipeline parallelism like this:
Worker 1: Reads and preprocesses the first image.
Worker 2: Filters the preprocessed image while Worker 1 preprocesses the next image.
Worker 3: Analyzes the filtered image while Workers 1 and 2 continue working on their tasks.
Therefore, pipeline parallelism ensures that the overall throughput of processing multiple images increases although each task remains sequential.
